# Migrating Application to IIS7.5

Tags: iis, dotnet-framework

I have a web application built in .Net 3.5.
Due to an upgrade to IIS7.5, I have recomplied the application using .net 4.0.
Everything seems to be fine when debugging via the development server however when using IIS, I get the following error when trying to access an aspx file.

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
>   The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
>   Detailed Error Information
>   Module  StaticFileModule
>   Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
>   Handler StaticFile
>   Error Code  0x80070032
>   Requested URL   http://localhost:80/pij/service/Gateway.aspx
>   Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pij\service\Gateway.aspx
>   Logon Method    Anonymous
>   Logon User  Anonymous

Prior to changing the application's app pool to v4.0 Classic I was getting the following.

> HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
>   An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

If anyone has any ideas how I can fix this, I'd be most grateful
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 tips that might be usefull:

- Try to sett the application poorl to Classic .NET see http://www.gtrifonov.com/blog/2009/02/27/IIS_7_HTTP_Error_404_17_The_requested_content_appe.aspx
- Be sure .aspx handler is mapping to the right path (c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64**v4.0.30319**\aspnet_isapi.dll)
- Be sure you have the website running in 4.0

HTH!

Comment: thanks, getting closer but still not there. 1 is good, 2 seems fine, 3 - I presume you mean that it was compiled using ver 4 right?

Comment: 3 - yes i meant that. Please try also to see if by any change you have aspx in the mime types... if so remove it as this is not a static file...